# How can I setup and execute reports using ReportNG

Tags: selenium, testng, reportng

I'm using TestNG to execute my selenium test but now I would like to output the contents to a more understandable format for my team using ReportNG.  I've done some search but haven't been able to find anything useful on how to setup and successfully use ReportNG .  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Normally reportng integrated with the testng following link will help you [click here](http://gm.matias.ph/internet-technology/java-ee-android/running-testng-integrated-with-reportng-in-eclipse-ide/).

Comment: i tried to follow this tutorial to the 't' but i just couldn't get it to work but thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

You can Use Apache Ant ,its very gud report generating tool for testng

Comment: i followed you tip and found http://earlwillis.wordpress.com/2012/01/31/getting-started-with-junit-reports/ most useful